# Calculate values in new columns

Tags: sql-server

I have an input data like,

```
---------------------------------------
M/Y | Total | Con | Est | Keep |  
----------------------------------
May-16 | 1000  | 100    | 200  | 500   |  
Jun-16 | 5000  | 500   | 1000 | 2000  |  
Jul-16 | 10000 | 1000  | 2500 | 5000  |  

----------------
```

I need Output like,

```
--------------------
M/Y | Total | Con | Con(%) | Est | Est(%) | Keep | Keep(%) |    
----------------------------------
May-16 | 1000  | 100 | 10%   | 200 | 20%  | 500 | 50%  |  
Jun-16 | 5000  | 500 | 10%   | 1000 | 20% | 2000 | 40%  |  
Jul-16 | 10000 | 1000 | 10% | 2500 | 25% | 5000 | 50%  |  


---------------------------
```

NOTE : Here the `Con(%),Est(%),Keep(%)` is calculated on the `Total` value.
EX: `Con(%) = (Con/Total)*100`

Can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `total` is never 0:

```
select
    t.*
    , cast(100 * con / total as varchar) + '%' [con(%)],
    , cast(100 * est / total as varchar) + '%' [est(%)],
    , cast(100 * keep / total as varchar) + '%' [keep(%)]
from your_table t;
```

If `total` can be `0`, one sensible output is `NULL` which in this case can be achieved by replacing `total` with `NULLIF(total,0)`.

Comment: If `total` can be `0`, then replace it with `NULLIF(total,0)`. This will avoid _divide by 0_ errors.